# Jumping Out of two Loops in a row in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that will

1. show my text for 1 second, clear itself then
2. print an 8*8 block of random numbers 100000 times (moving number decoration) and then
3. quit when I hit a key.

Here is my code:

```
#include stdio;
#include stdlib;
main() {
    printf("Welcome to random number V2.0");
    usleep(1000);
    printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
    printf("Press X to terminate at any time");
    usleep(1000);
    printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
    printf("Program starting");
    usleep(500);
    printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
    for(index=0;index<100000;index++) {
        Randomnumber;
        printf("%s". matrix)
        usleep(5);
        printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
        usleep(5);

    }

    Randomnumber() {
        int matrix[9][9];
        int index_x;
        int index_y;
        int index;
        for (index_x=0;index_x<9;index_x++) {
            for (index_y=0;index_y<9;index_y++) {
                /*randomizer code goes here, till change ran# statement*/
                matrix [index_x][index_y] = ran
#;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I need a way to halt the program in the for loop. I have found a function that would return a non-NULL value if a key is in the keyboard `buffer(kbhit)`, but I dont see how that can let me jump out of two loops. 
(Sorry for my sloppy code. `Kbhit` and `usleep` are not in the usual C library, but it works fine with `lcc`.)

Comment: OT: is `Randomnumber;` intentional? just curious.

Comment: This does not look like a valid syntax. In general, if you need to exit multiple loops, you can use `goto`. Yes, the "considered harmful" statement. You can also return from the middle of the inner loop.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight +1 for `goto` - it's about time people stop mindlessly repeating how "evil" it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` would work.

So would `index_x = 100, index_y = 100; break;`

---

Method A:

```
Randomnumber() 
{
    int matrix[9][9], x, y;
    for (x=0;  x<9;  ++x)
        for (y=0;  y<9;  ++y)
        {
            matrix [x][y] = rand();
            if (some condition which means we're done)
                 x = 100, y = 100;
        }
}
```

Method B:

```
Randomnumber() 
{
    int matrix[9][9], x, y;
    for (x=0;  x<9;  ++x)
        for (y=0;  y<9;  ++y)
        {
            matrix [x][y] = rand();
            if (some condition which means we're done)
                 return;
        }
}
```

Comment: @alexforC:  I added examples of both methods.  Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

you could change `Randomnumber()` to return a value:  maybe 1 for "Interrupted"; 0 for success.

Then the loop in main becomes

```
 for (...) {
   if (Randomnumber() != 0) {break;}
   ...
 }
```

(note also that you need a `()` to actually call the function from main.
And it is good practice to declare your return types and arguments, even if they are just (void).  *Default return types are so 1978*)